# タブレットでChromeブラウザ でoption 要素が disabled しない

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

シンプルなOption要素でDisabledしたいのですが、タブレットでChromeから見るとDisabledされません。

```html
<select name="fruits">
  <option value="peach" disabled>peach</option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="pine">pine</option>
</select>
```

jqueryで条件に一致したものだけにDisableを与えました。

```
 $('select[name="fruits"] > option[value="peach"]').attr('disabled');
```

Firefoxなどでは表示されるのですが、タブレットのChromeだけどうも表示されないようです。

Comment: `select`と`option`が逆でした。「タブレット」とはAndroid端末でしょうか？（iPadの場合、Chrome / Firefoxに関係なく内部はSafariなはずなので）また「表示されない」とはどういう状態を期待し、どういう状態だったのでしょうか？ 挙げられた jQueryのコードは単に属性値を取得するだけで、変更するものではないです。

Answer (score 0):

Android タブレットで試してみましたが、`disabled` された  `<option>` は選べませんが、見た目が他と同じなのはおかしいですね。単に Chrome のバグなのではないでしょうか。https://new.crbug.com/ でバグを登録しましょう。

Comment: バグの登録してみます。皆さんありがとうございました！